# I need to compile Borland C++ programs in VSCode but I encounter errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, borland-c++

I need to be able to compile Borland C++ programs in VSCode. At first, I received errors regarding the includes, but I was able to fix them. After that, I started receiving this error:

```
Error E2075: Incorrect command line option: -fdiagnostics-color=always.
```

Does anyone know what I can do to configure VSCode with Borland C++ and setup all the configuration files?

Here is my current `tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build bcc32",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bcc32 demo.cpp",
            "args": [
               
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
        },
        {
            "label": "Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "demo.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: 1. Why do you need this? 2. This file doesn't contain `-fdiagnostics-color=always`, so you're not using it. What do you press to start the build?

Comment: The company I work at has a very important project that was made in Borland C++, but only a few machines have licenses and they are not always able to access them. So they want a way to debug and run code in VSCode. I either press CTRL+F5 or I go directly to the file and press the Run button

Comment: If it is a very important project it deserves some care and attentention. Or are the CPU's soo old there are no current compilers that support it. I doubt the word "important" here, it means we cannot change it because we have no tests. And you might bypass the licences on borland IDE this way, but you will still be using (possibly unlicenced instances) of the borland compiler.

Comment: They don't want to change anything and the policy does not allow us to use unlicenced instances unfortunately so I have to do it this way. I thought about using it with Code Blocks if with VsCode I don't find a solution

Comment: does your machine have a Borland C++ license, how do expect to debug the code without a license, does it all work on the command line OUTSIDE VSC

Comment: they gave me a folder with the borland compiler

Comment: but the license is not in the folder, if they have done it a bit correct

Comment: It does not work on the command linie. The compiler is detected but it says things about how it cant include the libraries used

Comment: if you can't get it to work on the command line how do you suppose to get it to work in VSC, you have to emulate what you do on the CL